# Find label starting with text with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some labels, like:

```
<label>Some words</label>
<label>Some other words</label>
<label>Yet another words</label>
```

How can I get labels starting with "Some" (or other text?). I tried

```
$("label").filter('html^="Some"')
//or
$("label").filter('text^="Some"')
```

but it doesn't seem to work (returns empty list). It's more complicated in my real problem so maybe I made some other mistake, but maybe I'm doing it totally wrong? Is any of these a good way to do it? What's the best way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/ZTgw7/)):

```
$('label').filter(function(index) {
  return $(this).text().search('Some') == 0;
})...
```